# iOS 11 - UserDefaults.standard string value nil

Tags: ios, xcode

Whilst trying to retrieve values stored in UserDefaults.standard, i'm currently finding that a string value set within the Root.plist is not being read as expected; it has a default value assigned to it from within the Xcode storyboard UI (e.g. http://www.google.com), but when it is read within the ViewController swift code it is nil.

Within the ViewController's viewDidLoad(), I am calling

```
    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [String : Any]())
```

Within the ViewController's viewWillAppear(), i then try to read the string value as follows:

```
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var defaultURL = userDefaults.string(forKey: "server_url")
```

But defaultURL is nil. Not entirely sure what is going on here! Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register concrete key(s) and value(s)

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["server_url" : "http://www.google.com/"])
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciated - but why do we need to do this? Surely i just want to take the default value stored from the UI widget and then use that forever, rather than having to programmatically do this each time? Perhaps i'm missing something as to what the XCode Storyboard UI does? Might as well leave that blank in the Storyboard editor it seems...

Comment: The purpose of registering default values in `UserDefaults` is to have a defined state on the first launch of the application. If a different value is saved later this value is used. After deleting the preference file or reinstalling the app the value is reverted to the default value.

Comment: Okay, that helps to clarify, thanks - so when we have a Settings bundle value that is out of sync on first startup of the app (e.g. Settings value is set to www.apple.com, and the `UserDefaults` value is being registered as you mentioned above to www.google.com) how do you resolve this? It looks like the settings bundle is out of sync with what I have set programmatically...

Comment: Of course you have to register the value (as soon as possible for example in `applicationWillFinishLauching`) and then retrieve it and set the corresponding element in `Settings`. Even if `register` is called on each launch the *default* value is only used until it's changed the first time.

Comment: Great - makes sense and it's working now - thanks for the great explanation